# Java Font Display Problem

Tags: java

I realize that, in my certain customer side, when I use the font provided by Graphics2D itself, and decrease the size by 1, it cannot display properly.

```
private void drawInformationBox(Graphics2D g2, JXLayer<? extends V> layer) {
    if (MainFrame.getInstance().getJStockOptions().getYellowInformationBoxOption() == JStockOptions.YellowInformationBoxOption.Hide) {
        return;
    }

    final Font oldFont = g2.getFont();
    final Font paramFont = new Font(oldFont.getFontName(), oldFont.getStyle(), oldFont.getSize());
    final FontMetrics paramFontMetrics = g2.getFontMetrics(paramFont);
    final Font valueFont = new Font(oldFont.getFontName(), oldFont.getStyle() | Font.BOLD, oldFont.getSize() + 1);
    final FontMetrics valueFontMetrics = g2.getFontMetrics(valueFont);
    /*
     * This date font cannot be displayed properly. Why?
     */
    final Font dateFont = new Font(oldFont.getFontName(), oldFont.getStyle(), oldFont.getSize() - 1);
    final FontMetrics dateFontMetrics = g2.getFontMetrics(dateFont);
```

Rest of the font is OK. Here is the screen shoot (See the yellow box. There are 3 type of different font within the yellow box) :
[alt text http://www.investalks.com/attachments/month_1005/10051420318460461ffea5a2f9.jpg](http://www.investalks.com/attachments/month_1005/10051420318460461ffea5a2f9.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show enough code to determine whether the size is actually the problem...

Having said that, your code will be easier to read if you use the `deriveFont()` API, as in

```
final Font dateFont = oldFont.deriveFont((float)(oldFont.getSize() - 1));
```

This may or may not address your problem. My money is on some locale setting, which is returning characters that have no glyphs in the current font.